# Paying tax on rental property in UK as a Canadian resident

Tags: income-tax, united-kingdom, canada, rental-property, canada-revenue-agency

We left the UK in 2013 and have rented our apartment to friends and family ever since.
We make almost no money from the rental, it barely covers costs and have had to pay out for repairs since we have left the UK. We were unaware we would be liable to taxation as we make no money from the rental.
Now I'm told we will be liable for taxation and fines for late filing. What should we do next?

Comment: Didn't you fill out T1135 ever?  The question is pretty clear.  I would ask a LAWYER about voluntary disclosure.  https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/programs/about-canada-revenue-agency-cra/voluntary-disclosures-program-overview.html

Comment: Are you asking about Canadian or UK tax?

Comment: Canadian Taxation. Sorry should have made that clearer in the OP.